# condition based setState for counters

Tags: reactjs, setstate

learning from [some tutorial docs](http://buildwithreact.com/tutorial/state), I'm trying to update the counter (increment / reset) depending on the condition, below is the actual code on the tutorial

```
var CowClicker = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      clicks: 10,
      val:1                   // this has been added by me
    };
  },

  onCowClick: function(evt) {
    this.setState({
      clicks: this.state.clicks + 1,
      val: this.state.val * this.state.clicks,  // code part in question
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Clicks: {this.state.clicks}</div>
        <div>Val: {this.state.val}</div>
        <img
          src="http://s3.bypaulshen.com/buildwithreact/cow.png"
          onClick={this.onCowClick}
          className="cow"
        />
        <p>Click the cow</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CowClicker />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Now, I'm trying to put condition based reset as below but it won't work :

```
  onCowClick: function(evt) {
    this.setState({
      clicks: this.state.clicks + 1,
      alert(this.state.val),
      if(this.state.val > 1000000){ //this is not working
        val: 1,
      }else{
        val: this.state.val * this.state.clicks,
      }
    });
  },
```

This question might be way too obvious or stupid that's why I'm not getting a pointer on web as to where I'm wrong? 
Can `setState` not operate on logical operators? Is it purely to set stuffs or play around with using function calls (e.g. links searched [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338577/reactjs-concurrent-setstate-race-condition) | [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235298/update-this-state-conditionally-when-rendering-component-in-react))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Provide

```
{
  clicks: this.state.clicks + 1,
  alert(this.state.val),
  if(this.state.val > 1000000){ //this is not working
    val: 1,
  }else{
    val: this.state.val * this.state.clicks,
  }
}
```

as a parameter which must either be an object or a function to your [`setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) call.

Your `if` is somewhere within the object, that can't work as far as I know :-)

Provide an object:

```
onCowClick: function(evt) {
  const val = this.state.val > 1000000 ? 1 : this.state.val * this.state.clicks;
  alert(this.state.val);
  this.setState({
    clicks: this.state.clicks + 1,
    val: val,
  });
},
```

Provide a function:

```
onCowClick: function(evt) {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    const val = prevState.val > 1000000 ? 1 : prevState.val * prevState.clicks;
    return {
      clicks: prevState.clicks + 1,
      val: val,
    };
  });
},
```

Whereof the latter would be more correct, as you will refer to the current state and the first could refer to a outdated state.

Comment: if i break down `const val = this.state.val > 1000000 ? 1 : this.state.val * this.state.clicks;` into `if` condition instead of ternary condition, it wont work, is there a reason to it?

Comment: If you put the if at the very same position as the `const val = ` it should work. You can't put it inside the object declaration. Was that the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`setState` either accepts a new object (updater) or a callback.

```
this.setState({
  clicks: this.state.clicks + 1,
  val: this.state.val > 1000000 ? 1 : this.state.val * this.state.clicks,
})
```

as a callback example:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  clicks: prevState.clicks + 1,
  val: prevState.val > 1000000 ? 1 : prevState.val * prevState.clicks,
}))
```

Should you need to execute any other action right after state has been updated:

```
this.setState({
  clicks: this.state.clicks + 1,
  val: this.state.val > 1000000 ? 1 : this.state.val * this.state.clicks,
}, () => {
  // your next action
})
```

Please refer the [ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more information.